# when remove website to another server?

Tags: web, hosting, cpanel

i have website 
http://www.daadouchgroup.com/web/index.php?ACT=8&LNG=Ar
and i move this website to another server but he not work without username of the cpenel in the url like this 
http://xxx.xx.xxx.x/~daadouchgroup/web/index.php?ACT=4&LNG=Ar
how can i fix that ??
and have another problem the data in database in arabic language but when i show it in the new website it's show not correct how can i fix this problem can some body help me ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are shifting your site to a new server, you will have to point to domain to the new server. For this you will have to change the nameservers pointing to new server. DNS changes will take a max of 48hrs to propagate.

You will have to use utf-8 meta encoding and decoding technique